# Google Kubernetes Engine Ingress UNHEALTHY backend service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

> **Kind Note:** I have googled a lot and take a look too many questions related to this issue at StackOverflow also but couldn't solve my issue, that's why don't mark this as duplicate, please!

I'm trying to deploy 2 services (One is Python flask and other is NodeJS) on Google Kubernetes Engine. I have created two Kubernetes-deployments one for each service and two Kubernetes-services one for each service of type `NodePort`. Then, I have created an Ingress and mentioned my `endpoints` but Ingress says that One backend service is `UNHEALTHY`.

Here are my Deployments YAML definitions:

```
# Pyservice deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pyservice
  labels:
    app: pyservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: pyservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pyservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pyservice
        image: docker.io/arycloud/docker_web_app:pyservice
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
      imagePullSecrets:
         - name: docksecret

# # Nodeservice deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodeservice
  labels:
    app: nodeservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: nodeservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodeservice
        tier: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodeservice
        image: docker.io/arycloud/docker_web_app:nodeservice
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
         - name: docksecret
```

And, here are my services and Ingress YAML definitions:

```
# pyservcie service
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pyservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: pyservice
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    nodePort: 30001
---

# nodeservcie service
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nodeservcie
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nodeservcie
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    nodePort: 30002
---

# Ingress

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: pyservice
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: pyservice
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /node/svc/
        backend:
          serviceName: nodeservcie
          servicePort: 8080
```

The `pyservice` is working fine but the `nodeservice` shows as `UNHEALTHY` backend. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Even I have edited the `Firewall Rules` for all `gke-....` and allow all ports just for getting out from this issue, but it still showing the `UNHEALTHY` status for `nodeservice`.

What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just had the same problem like two days, at the end it was because my app was redirecting "/" path to path "/b", and for cheking health you must not redirect in "/", you app must return 200

Comment: I have tested this service container locally and it's working right.

Comment: this is likely not a firewall rule issue, can you curl the exposed service though the nodeport to see if you get a 200 response? curl [node_IP]:30002

Comment: Hi @PatrickW, thanks for hitting up here, do both services need to return 200 at `/` or first service only need?

Comment: each service will act as a separate backend, so each one is probed separately and needs to return 200

Comment: Without showing `Ingress` object contents it's hard to say. I'm not familiar with GCE. The `Service` YAML spec has `type: NodePort`, which if not given will pick a static port from the `--service-node-port-range`.  You can then create your own Load Balancer, or HTTP Reverse Proxy to pass traffic to this static `NodePort` on the cluster nodes.  If your cluster supports auto-LB creation it will set up backing nodes with `NodePort`.  However, usually with `Ingress`, the idea is that the Kubernetes cluster's Ingress Controller will set this up.

Comment: Maybe try reviewing the GCP annotations [in this section of k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a GCE ingress class and then specifying a nginx rewrite annotation? In case you haven't realised, the annotation won't do anything to the GCE ingress.

You have also got 'nodeservcie' as your selector instead of 'nodeservice'.

Comment: I have fixed the typo issues and remove all annotations from ingress, again one service goes to the unhealthy state for a while but after some moments comes back to healthy again, why this is happening?